# Automatic saving of files history in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, history

I just want to know whether it is possible in Android studio to save the history of the project automatically? The problem for me is that if I can some files and later realize that the changes were not that good, it is difficult to get back to the last versions of the files. Of course, I can do this manually by always copying the folders with all files. But this turns out to be inconvenient.

I'd appreciate every comment.

Comment: Use Git. In Android Studio it's very easy. [Easy Version Control With Git in Android Studio](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-git-in-android-studio--cms-30514)

Comment: you can check your last 12 hours history in Android studio -> vcs -> local history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The history of your project is automatically saved in android studio.

1. Just click on VCS
2. Select Local history
3. Click on show history

[image: See this image] for more help

Or you can also learn version control with git. From [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-git-in-android-studio--cms-30514)

Comment: Thanks Abhishek for your answer. It helped a lot. Would you personally advice me to use version control with git or do you think that the VSC is enough?

Comment: Thanks Abhishek for your comment. Unfortunately I do not have Facebook (this is not joke; I have never used it). Still thanks for your help. I accepted your answer.